# Android chrome, detect cards / tabs group bar on bottom of window

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Case: New chrome browsers allow grouping tabs, if the user scroll top, the bottom bar with grouped tabs appears, and it's covering some part of the page.

My question is: How to detect that bar, its height, it is some kinda object I can refer to, detect, or something. Mean something like window.tabgroup.

[image]